# Segmentation Fault while reading tsv in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a tsv file in python pandas but get the error "Segmentation Fault". Below is the code i used -

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_loc, sep='\t', low_memory=False,dtype={'code':np.str})
```

This code was working fine with another test file i was using until now.

Comment: It seems need `{'code':str}`

Comment: i removed that part, but no help, still the same. @jezrael

Comment: So sorry, I think problem is with some bad data. :(

Comment: Check out this post, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25834174/6163621. Basically says add `engine = 'python'` but seems to be more of a workaround than a true solution.

Comment: What is the size of the file? Try to find the part of file, for which it fails: like, splitting into two and then trying to load both files.